# Failed to unmarshal discovery data for component: CONTINUOUS_PROC with more than one ContinuousQuery listener in Ignite

Tags: java, caching, ignite

I'm trying to play with Ignite (v2.8.0) and ContinuousQuery-es on my local machine.
My setup is one server node and two clients.

The problem is once server node started and first client connected and listening for updates with ContinuousQuery any other subsequent client failing with following exception:

`[ERROR] 2020-04-18 20:00:18.436 [tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4] TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to unmarshal discovery data for component: CONTINUOUS_PROC`

I also spot it keeps failing until query cursor is closed in first client (once closed any other **single** client can connect).

Server node code:

```
public class IgniteServerCacheBootstrap {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IgniteCacheClient.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteCheckedException, InterruptedException {

        IgniteConfiguration serverConfig = new IgniteConfiguration()
                .setGridLogger(new Log4J2Logger("log4j2.xml"));

        Ignite server = Ignition.start(serverConfig);
        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }

}
```

Client node code (mostly taken from Ignite samples)
I'm trying to run two of such nodes in parallel:

```
public class IgniteCacheClient implements Serializable {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IgniteCacheClient.class);

    private IgniteCache igniteCache;

    public IgniteCacheClient() throws IgniteCheckedException {
        IgniteConfiguration clientConfig = new IgniteConfiguration()
                .setGridLogger(new Log4J2Logger("log4j2.xml"))
                .setClientMode(true);

        Ignite client = Ignition.getOrStart(clientConfig);
        igniteCache = client.getOrCreateCache("MY_CACHE");
    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {

        // Create new continuous query.
        ContinuousQuery<Integer, String> qry = new ContinuousQuery<>();

        qry.setInitialQuery(new ScanQuery<>(new IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Integer key, String val) {
                return key > 10;
            }
        }));

        // Callback that is called locally when update notifications are received.
        qry.setLocalListener(new CacheEntryUpdatedListener<Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends String>> evts) {
                for (CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends String> e : evts)
                    logger.info("Updated entry [key=" + e.getKey() + ", val=" + e.getValue() + ']');
            }
        });

        // This filter will be evaluated remotely on all nodes.
        // Entry that pass this filter will be sent to the caller.
        qry.setRemoteFilterFactory(new Factory<CacheEntryEventFilter<Integer, String>>() {
            @Override
            public CacheEntryEventFilter<Integer, String> create() {
                return new CacheEntryEventFilter<Integer, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean evaluate(CacheEntryEvent<? extends Integer, ? extends String> e) {
                        return e.getKey() > 10;
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        // Execute query.
        QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Integer, String>> cur = igniteCache.query(qry);

        // Iterate through existing data.
        for (Cache.Entry<Integer, String> e : cur)
            logger.info("Queried existing entry [key=" + e.getKey() + ", val=" + e.getValue() + ']');

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

Full exception

```
[ERROR] 2020-04-18 20:00:18.436 [tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4] TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to unmarshal discovery data for component: CONTINUOUS_PROC
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object with given class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:132) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:93) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshalZip(IgniteUtils.java:10248) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.unmarshalData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:340) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket.unmarshalGridData(DiscoveryDataPacket.java:155) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.onExchange(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2069) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.processNodeAddFinishedMessage(ClientImpl.java:2219) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.processDiscoveryMessage(ClientImpl.java:2088) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1930) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$1.body(ClientImpl.java:302) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:61) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Failed to find cache for name: MY_CACHE
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.readResolve(GridCacheContext.java:2376) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1248) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2076) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.readExternal(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:2192) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.readExternal(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1706) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2.readExternal(CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2.java:179) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1409) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.readMap(IgniteUtils.java:5409) [ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor$DiscoveryData.readExternal(GridContinuousProcessor.java:2446) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:124) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find cache for name: MY_CACHE
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.readResolve(GridCacheContext.java:2371) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1248) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2076) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.readExternal(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:2192) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.readExternal(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1706) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2.readExternal(CacheContinuousQueryHandlerV2.java:179) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1409) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2176) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.readMap(IgniteUtils.java:5409) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor$DiscoveryData.readExternal(GridContinuousProcessor.java:2446) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:2116) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2065) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.jdk.JdkMarshaller.unmarshal0(JdkMarshaller.java:124) ~[ignite-core-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Failed to find cache for name: MY_CACHE"

I think that your `private IgniteCache igniteCache` is being transferred with your lambdas. Please try converting all of your anonymous inner classes to named static inner classes. I'm talking about predicates, listeners and factories.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!